# How to save vCard information from QR code into Android contact app via Phonegap/ZXing?

Tags: android, cordova, qr-code, zxing, vcf-vcard

I'm creating an Android Barcode Scanner app using PhoneGap with ZXing plugins. Currently, it is able to decode and differentiate all QR code result headers and act accordingly.

For example:

1. ***tel:1234567890*** launches the phone dialer;
2. ***smsto:12345:blablabla*** launches the messaging app;
3. ***geo:111.111,222.222*** launches the mapping app;
4. ***http://website.com*** launches the browser; and etc.

The app is now left with ***vCard*** and ***iCal***.

My question is how to launch the ***"create contact card/form"*** from the native contact app that is pre-filled with information found in the ***vCard*** string (fetched from QR code) and ask if you would like to save the contact? Same goes to ***iCal*** that will launch the calendar app pre-filled with information found in the ***iCal*** string.

Thanks in advance!